# ASP.net Core IIS EXPRESS 404

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-express

I am developing a net core 3.1 web application.
One of authentication schemes is Certificate, so I want to protect a page with client certificate authentication.
This is Web.config IIS configuration (Obviously i set `<section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow"` in solution applicationHostConfig ):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44300" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="certificate/login">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <access sslFlags="Ssl,SslNegotiateCert,SslRequireCert" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <access sslFlags="Ssl" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Application starts successfully, and when I call localhost://33400/Certificate/login, browser show certificate page handshake correctly, I choose a certificate and ... IIS surprise me with 
404 Static File Handler! All others pages work perfectly.

[image]

I am struggle with this error, please someone help me.

Comment: If your application does not have a Certificate controller and login method, 404 is expected.

Comment: My application have a certificate controller with login action

Comment: Then check why ASP.NET Core pipeline has been bypassed, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: I activate IISEXPRESS tracelog and log and the result is 404. The difference from other actions is: 
<EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000188-0003-E900-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="OldHandlerName"></Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerName">StaticFile</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerModules">StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerScriptProcessor"></Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerType"></Data>
 </EventData>

Comment: It seem that new AspNetCoreModuleV2 not recognize this configuration, looking at traces iis try all modules (IsapiFilterModule, ApplicationInitializationModule, WebSocketModule, ConfigurationValidationModule, httpRedirectionModule, ....) but not AspNetCoreModuleV2, so ends with staticFile and 404

Comment: I opened an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21193

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @treborgero in aspnet core issue [Optional client certificates #21193](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21193)

TIP: Make sure you remove the `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` tag
and it work like a charm!